# Android Room @Embedded annotation compilation fails for @NonNull annotated constructor parameters of a POJO defined in a library module

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a POJO which I am embedding in a Room Entity; Please note that the **POJO is defined in a library module**;

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String uuid;

    @Embedded
    @NonNull
    private Address address;

    public Person(@NonNull String uuid, @NonNull Address address) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.address = address;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}


public class Address {
    @NonNull
    private String street;

    @NonNull
    private String city;

    public Address(@NonNull String street, @NonNull String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}


@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Person")
    List<Person> getPersons();
}



@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
@Database(entities = {Person.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class PersonDb extends RoomDatabase {
    private static volatile PersonDb INSTANCE;

    public abstract PersonDao getPersonDao();
}
```

Compilation fails with

> "Error:Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You
>   can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match
>   the fields (by name and type)."
>   Error:Cannot find setter for field.

If I remove `@NonNull` annotation from the constructors parameters to Address POJO, the code compiles fine.
Also, if the same POJO is in the app module, code compiles.

As can be seen, `Address` class does have a public constructor.

What am I missing here? What is the definition of `usable constructor` in Room's perspective? Or it is an issue with Room?

Comment: Do you happen to use jacoco for code coverage? I get this error only when jacoco is enabled.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. is any one knows..

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says: 
"[To persist a field, Room must have access to it. You can make a field public, or you can provide a getter and setter for it. If you use getter and setter methods, keep in mind that they're based on JavaBeans conventions in Room.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#kotlin)"

`uuid` and `address` are declared as `private` in `Person`, you have getters for those but no setters.
So you can create setters or declare them as `public`.