# Room Database compile error: Field has non-unique column name

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I'm getting this error on some of the fields of my class

> error: Field has non-unique column name

```
@Entity(tableName = "Team", foreignKeys = {
    @ForeignKey(entity = Group.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "groupId")},
    indices = {@Index("groupId")})
public class Team {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private long groupId;
    @SerializedName("Team")
    private String name;
    private String englishName;
    @SerializedName("Played")
    private int played;
    @SerializedName("Victories")
    private int win;
    @SerializedName("Draws")
    private int draw;
    @SerializedName("Defeats")
    private int defeat;
    @SerializedName("Made")
    private int goalFor;
    @SerializedName("Let")
    private int goalAgainst;
    @SerializedName("Diff")
    private int goalDiff;
    @SerializedName("Points")
    private int points;

    public Team() {

    }

    /* getter and setter methods */
}
```

For example, i get this error on "win" , "draw", "groupId". But not on "id" or "name". And as you can see it's a compile error and it doesn't provide anymore information about the error except that sentence in the title.

**Edit:** I tried changing the name of variables but it didn't work.

**Edit:** Getter and setter methods for "win", other methods look exactly like this one.

```
public int getWin() {
    return win;
}

public void setWin(int win) {
    this.win = win;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your getter and setter for `win` ?

Comment: Just added the methods.

Comment: Try adding `@ColumnInfo(name = “xxxx”)` to the fields to specify how you want them to be called in the SQL table, maybe Serialized Name is conflicting? I’m not sure. In any case, I’d make them public and remove the getter/setter unless you really need them.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: I've found something, explained it with an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a prefix in order to avoid columns name duplication. From the official documentation:

prefix
String prefix ()
Specifies a prefix to prepend the column names of the fields in the embedded fields.

For the example above, if we've written:

> @Embedded(prefix = "foo_")    Coordinates coordinates;

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded.html#prefix()

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (well, not actually a solution).
I have another entity called "Group":

```
@Entity
public class Group {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @Embedded
    private List<Team> teams;

    public Group() {

    }

    public Group(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /* getter and setter methods */
```

Turns out that The variable "teams" with "Embedded" annotation was the source of my problems. when i remove it, the code works just fine. If someone could explain to me what i did wrong (or did i?) i'd appreciate it.

**Edit:** Found some links related to this problem.

[Android Room @Embedded annotation compilation fails for @NonNull annotated constructor parameters of a POJO defined in a library module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115995/android-room-embedded-annotation-compilation-fails-for-nonnull-annotated-const)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/318